# What is the best way to to store user specific data in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I want every user (windows user) to have his/her own settings in my app. What's the best way to do that?

Should I check for the username or is it done automatically? Will it be compatible with every Windows version from XP through to Windows 8?

Comment: It is sharing settings between users that's very hard to do.  Use settings or Environment.GetFolderPath() to get the appdata path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a settings.settings to your project.

Comment: and there is no need to check the username?

Answer (score 1):

If you add settings properties to your project then you could specify USER and APPLICATION settings predefined for your application.
When the application run, you update the settings specific for the current user and then you save these settings calling

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

this method will create a file called `user.config` under the path

```
%AppData%\CompanyName\ExeName_Url_hashcode\Version\
```

containing the settings for the current user.
This file will be reloaded when the same user will restart your application.
You don't have to do any further work. The saved USER settings will be there to use.